# Rails combining RegEx with render to selectively render templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, render, partial-views

Let's assume I have the following partials:

```
_o1_some_note.html.erb
_o2_other_note.html.erb
_o3_last_note.html.erb
...
```

I would like to render as many partials as a `@counter` variable allows, like so:

```
# Controller
def view
  @counter = 2
end

# View

<% (1..@counter).each do |c| %>
  <%= render "o#{c}" %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that the above fails because `o1`, `o1`, `o3` are not the actual names of the partials. But I'm wondering if there's a way around this, to only provide the `o#` part, because the rest of the partial name is more for internal organization. And this way, the code is more clean.

So this would be basically saying, render the template file that matches this description (using RegEx or whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can glob the file from the directory, then pull its name out for rendering.  For instance:

```
<% Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/views/partial/location/_#{c}*"].each do |file_path| %>
  <%= render file_path.split("/").last %>
<% end %>
```